# How can I write a method to shift the members of a String array without using java.util.Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm struggling to finish a project requiring me to create my own `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` classes. I've got a method that adds a `String` to an `ArrayStringList` object (adds an 'item' to the list), which works fine.

However, I also need the method to be able to detect if an index in the `String` array already has a string stored at that index. And if it does, it needs to shift all items on the list to the right of the selected index to make space for the new string to be added.

So, I've got two other methods to help with that. One of my methods, `hasItem()`, is used to tell whether the index of an array already has a string stored there (i.e., items[index] != null). That block of code in my if-else statement seems to execute just fine. However, I'm not sure that I am implementing my other method, `shiftRight()`, correctly, as the method appears to just replace the string at the selected index rather than move it to the right.

```
public boolean add(int index, String item) {
        boolean op = false;
        if (hasItem(index)) {
                shiftRight(index);
                items[index] = item;
                size += 1;
                op = true;
        } else {
                items[index] = item;
                size += 1;
                op = true;
        } //if
        return op;
} //add

private boolean hasItem(int index) {
        boolean op = false;
        if (items[index] == null)) {
                op = false;
        } else if (items[index] != null)) {
                op = true;
        } //if
        return op;
} //hasItem

private boolean arraySizeInc() {
        boolean op = false;
        int sizeInc = items.length + 10;
        this.items = new String[sizeInc];
        if (items.length == sizeInc) {
                op = true;
        } else {
                op = false;
        } //if
        return op;
} //arraySizeInc

private boolean shiftRight(int index) {
        boolean op = false;
        for (int i = size(); i >= index; i--) {
                if (items.length == size()) {
                        arraySizeInc();
                        items[i + 1] = items[i];
                        op = true;
                } else {
                        items[i + 1] = items[i];
                        op = true;
                } //if
        } //for
        return op;
} //shiftRight
```

Other methods mentioned:

1. `size()` just returns an instance variable representing the 'size' of the array. It's inherited from an abstract class within the `ArrayStringList` class's default constructor. NOTE: The size is supposed to be different from the length of the array, as the `size()` method is supposed to be usable by both the `ArrayStringList` and `LinkedList` classes. Hence, the reason why size is incremented every time an item is added to the list instead of just keeping track of the array's length.
2. `arraySizeInc()` increases the *length* of the array by 10 by creating a new array which holds all the members of the previous array. This is only done when the length of the array (which, by default, is 10) is about to be exceeded by its 'size'.

I've omitted any exceptions that were thrown or caught within each method's code for readability.

EDIT: Added note concerning `size()`.

EDIT2: So, here's the `ListDriver` program I'm using to test each method:

```
public class ListDriver {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                //StringList is an interface for ArrayStringList
                StringList s1;

                //Object created with default size of zero and
                //a String array with a default length of 10.
                s1 = new ArrayStringList();

                //This test works fine.    
                s1.add(0, "Hello!");
                //Outputs size: 1
                System.out.println("size: " + s1.size());
                //Outputs isEmpty: false
                System.out.println("isEmpty: " + s1.isEmpty());
                //Outputs add: Hello!
                System.out.println("add: " + s1.get(0));

                //This test does not work.
                //**Index 0 is still "Hello!" here.**
                s1.add(0, "Oy!");
                //Index 0 is now "Oy!".
                System.out.println("size: " + s1.size());
                //Outputs size: 2
                System.out.println("add1: " + s1.get(0));
                //Outputs add1: Oy!
                System.out.println("add2: " + s1.get(1));
                //**Outputs add2: null**
         } //main
} //class
```

The last line should output "add2: Hello!". For some reason, my `add()` method is not shifting the string at index 0 ("Hello!") to the next index before adding the new string. So, that string gets deleted and replaced by the new string.

EDIT3: Added my 'hasItem' method in case there is something there that's causing the issue. At this point, I think my 'shiftRight' method seems to be implemented correctly, but there's something else going on in my code that's causing 'add' not to work properly.

EDIT4: Added my 'arraySizeInc' method as well. I wonder if the issue is that this method is being called when it shouldn't, which is creating a new String array without copying over the values of the original array.

Comment: Just reading the code it looks OK.  Could you add a specific test case that you feel isn't working right?  Include the output, it'll make it easier to verify someone else testing the same code.

Comment: Sure thing. I just added a part of the ListDriver class I've been using to test the code along with the output in the comments. Hope this helps!

Comment: When I run the code, making only some basic obvious additions, I get correct output.  I don't think the error is in the code you are showing us.  Please show your full implementation of the list class.  Also please name the class something else, `ArrayList` is a system class and liable to cause all sorts of confusion.

Comment: I suspect that it's not my shiftRight method that's the problem, either. I'll post the other relevant methods once I have a chance. Also, ArrayList is not the actual name of my class. It's just what I'm calling it here so that people know what I'm talking about (the real name is ArrayStringList.java).

Comment: That would be a much better name to use when you post the full code.

Comment: Yes. I've changed the name to match my actual class name. I've also added my 'hasItem' method in case that is where the issue is originating.

Comment: The problem is not in `hasItem()`.  Please post full code.  I currently suspect `arraySizeInc()`.

Comment: You're probably right. I've added arraySizeInc() to the code. I suspect that the method is being called when it shouldn't be called, which is causing 'shiftRight' to create a new String array without copying over the values of the original array.

Comment: Your `arraySizeInc()` doesn't even bother to try to copy the elements already in the array.  Every time you call it you'll lose every element already stored in the array.  That's way that one element at the end prints as `null` in your test case.  It wasn't copied into the new array.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your code a little bit and defined some of your ambiguous methods. Run this code on its own and see if it's what you're looking for.
File name is "Sandbox.java"

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // init an array
        int[] items = {1,2,3,4,5,0};
        // size will be the length of the array, size() in your program, I believe
        int size = items.length;
        // size - 2 or else you would be looping out of the array, causing an index out of bounds error
        for (int i = size - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            items[i + 1] = items[i];
        }
        // expected result [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. The '1' at index 0 is the original '1' in the 'items' init
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));
    }
}
```

Let me know if this is the result you were looking for.

Comment: I forgot to specify that size() is actually different from the length of the array (that's because it's supposed to be used for my LinkedList class as well). My apologies. Otherwise, thanks for the help, I figure it's something to do with how I am using size/size() in my for loop, so I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

`arraySizeInc` needs to copy the elements already in the array.  Otherwise all elements in the array will just be `null` after any call to `arraySizeInc`.

If you're allowed to use the API calls, something like this:

```
   private void arraySizeInc() {
      items = Arrays.copyOf( items, items.length+10 );
   }
```

Or if your instructor wants you to do it yourself, this might work.

```
   private void arraySizeInc() {
      String[] temp = new String[ items.length + 10 ];
      for( int i = 0; i < items.length; i++ )
          temp[i] = items[i];
      items = temp;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized that I hadn't implemented the method to copy the elements of the array. I think that's where the issue lies.